# Do I need to do registerDefaults: every time the app starts?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing an iOS app with latest SDK.

I do this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [standardUserDefaults registerDefaults: [PreferenceDefaultValues dictionary]];
    [standardUserDefaults synchronize];

    return YES;
}
```

**Is it needed to do registerDefaults: every time the app starts?**

Comment: I have never seen this code in my life...Nor have I ever used it.  What is this supposedly doing?

Comment: @borrrden: See the documentation for `NSRegistrationDomain`. It provides a set of temporary defaults to ensure that searches will always be successful.

Comment: Is NSRegistrationDomain even relevant for iOS?

Comment: No need to register default for using preferences. Only necessary if you want a different default value from built-in. So if you do want a different default value than the default default value, yes you need to register every time. Otherwise, no need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the documentation for `registerDefaults:` states explicitly:

> The contents of the registration domain are not written to disk; you
>   need to call this method each time your application starts.

Note that for the same reason there is no need to call `synchronize` after `registerDefaults:`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes according to the apple documentation it is necessary:

> If there is no registration domain, one is created using the specified
>   dictionary, and NSRegistrationDomain is added to the end of the search
>   list.   The contents of the registration domain are not written to
>   disk; **you need to call this method each time your application starts**.
>   You can place a plist file in the application's Resources directory
>   and call registerDefaults: with the contents that you read in from
>   that file.

When you are registering defaults you usually provide a custom plist file. So when you change a value its written to this plist file and when you get a value it is taken from this plist file.